# Could someone please explain the implementation of public-private key encryption for storing passwords?

Tags: rsa, public-key, passwords

As someone new to cryptography,I have a question about how logins work on websites. I understand mathematically how asymmetric encryption works and how https web requests work to securely send symmetric encryption keys. What I struggle to understand is how a website can have an encrypted version of my password stored that they aren't capable of deciphering, yet they can check the password is correct, without at any point sending data that would cause a breach. Maybe this is a dumb question but if anyone could point me in the right direction for resources to read that would be great.

Comment: You can start with the wikipedia entry on [password hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function#Password_verification), then follow the links from there. This will quickly get you into [key derivations functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function), [salts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)), [peppers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pepper_(cryptography)), as well as attacks such as [rainbow tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table). Once armed with the terminology, you will find a **lot** of related questions on this site.

Comment: @Marc thank you very much